# I don't understand this regexp match

Tags: javascript, regex

My input string is `"ssn"`.

My regexp is `/^(s)(s)?((n)(n)?)?$/`

Executing:

```
var regexp = /^(s)(s)?((n)(n)?)?$/;
var match = regexp.exec("ssn");
console.log(match);
```

Yields:

```
[
    "ssn",
    "s",
    "s",
    "n",
    "n",
    null
]
```

Why is the `"n"` in `"ssn"` matched 2 times ?

The desired output is:

```
[
    "ssn",
    "s",
    "s",
    "n",
    null,
    null
]
```

Comment: well you got 5 capture groups.

Comment: so you are trying to also match `ssnn` or `snn`?

Comment: shoot ur right! (not sarcastic), the 2 n matches are actually the same "n" in the string, thanks. I'll accept answer.

Comment: @epascarello "ssnn" also valid yes. these are actually function parameters (by type).

Comment: Answer I would have posted is: You have 5 capture groups so you are seeing the n twice because of the 3rd and 4th (nested) capture group. You can see it more clearly with 

```var regexp = /^(1)(2)?(3(4)(5)?)?$/;
var match = regexp.exec("12345");
console.log(match);```

or diagram https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%281%29%282%29%3F%283%284%29%285%29%3F%29%3F%24%2F

Comment: @epascarello yes someone closed this question, sorry about that.